# Hover Issue. HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Problem: The idea is the div that changes the colour of its contents on hover. Except the text and image (sprite) colours change at different points; the text on hover above the 'address' div and the image above the 'addressicon' div. Does anyone know how I could I get both to change on hover over the the 'address' div.

HTML:

```
<section id="gallery">
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:40px;">

        <div class="address"><div class="title"><span>Address</span></div><br>
            <div class="addressicon"></div>
            <p><br>Address1<br>
            Address2<br>
            Address3<br>
            Area<br>
            City<br>
            PostCode
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width:33%;height:400px;display:inline-block;background-color:#000000"></div>
        <div style="width:33%;height:400px;display:inline-block;background-color:#000000"></div>

    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
.address {
width:33%;
height:400px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#CCC;
color:#bcb7af;}

.address:hover {color:#000000;}

.address span {
color:#bcb7af;
align:center;
font-size:24px;
width:100%;}

.address:hover span {
color:#000000;}

.title {text-align:center;}

.addressicon {
background: url(../images/address.png) bottom;
width:202px;
height:130px;
margin: 0px auto;}

.addressicon:hover {
background-position: 0 0;}
```

**Many thanks**

**Problem Solved New CSS:**

```
.address > .addressicon {
    background: url(../images/address.png) bottom;}

.address:hover > .addressicon, {
    background-position: 0 0;}
```

Comment: If you want ancestors of the address element to change their styles when hovering over the address element (I think this is what you're asking?) Then you can't do that with pure css+html unfortunately, you'll need to look into a JavaScript/jQuery solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.address:hover > .addressicon {
    color: SOMETHING;
}
```

And never leave a `div` empty. Put an `&nbsp;` in it, to prevent it from stupid behaviors.

Comment: I didn't know that leaving a `div` empty caused weird behaviour? What kind of weird behaviour can it cause?

Comment: Sometimes, browser don't understand the closing tag and everything after it goes into the empty div.

Comment: Ok, after googling I think I see what you mean now, always good to learn something new!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the education regarding the empty div and your help. It solved the problem.